# Crontab is not working in ubuntu 16.04 for mysqldump

Tags: 16.04, cron

This is my `.my.cnf` file for user name and password,

```
[mysqldump]
user="root"
password=""
```

This is my `mysqldump.sh` file, which is working fine when I run `sh /home/user/mysqldump.sh` from terminal.

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/user/.my.cnf -u root -h localhost  database_name
```

Lastly I run `crontab -e` for add my cron job

```
* *   * * *   root    sh /home/user/mysqldump.sh | gzip -9 > /home/user/database/backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
```

When i run `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

```
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: The last message means that the command run by `cron` had some output for you. You didn't specify that you wanted any output redirected (using `>`) to a log file (or something like that) so `cron` tried to mail it to you. Then `cron` discovered that you had no MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) installed either. Then, not knowing what to do with the output, it discarded it. For future runs of this command you may want to know what the output is, so I recommend writing it to a log file.

Comment: There should be no user field (`root`) in a user crontab (`crontab -e`) - that's only for the system-wide cron jobs in `/etc/crontab`

Comment: @Jos, Thank you for your detail explanation. can you give me a sample code i just wanted to save backup file in my file system not send in mail.